# Fix (glue) the position of % values on parent resize

Tags: css

I have a div that sits at 15% width of the screen. On click, that width increases to 100%. It's basically a pop-out content area.

In order to center the icons inside of the original 15% width parent in a nice, responsive manner, they are set as such:

```
.parent
  position: relative;
  width: 15%;

.icons;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

This basically creates an aside on the left with an icon toggle. The icons are centered inside of `parent`. But, when the icon is clicked I resize the parent to slide out and become `width: 100%;`. All of a sudden, those nice percentage values change relative to the parent and move into the center of the screen. I want to freeze them so they don't move! In other words, I would like them to stay in the position they were in when the parent `div` was 15%.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ra6qa9jf/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to remove the icon div from the red box and give it a new parent. Then style the new parent to always have a width of 15% and to have position absolute so that it appears as a layer over the red box. So your new HTML might be:

```
<div class="parent"></div> //This is the red box, same styling as before
<div class="parent-2"> //This is the new parent container for the icons
    <div class="icons">
        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
    </div> //This is the icon, same as before
</div>
```

And the corresponding new CSS:

```
.parent-2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Lastly you'd just need to update your javascript so that the onClick listener changed the correct div width:

```
(function () {
    var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('parent')[0];
    var icons = document.getElementsByClassName('icons')[0],
      toggle = false;
  icons.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    toggle = +!toggle;

    if (toggle) {
      parent.style.width = "100%";
    } else {
      parent.style.width = "15%";
    }

  });
}());
```

Refer code:

```js
(function() {
  var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('parent')[0];
  var icons = document.getElementsByClassName('icons')[0],
    toggle = false;
  icons.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    toggle = +!toggle;

    if (toggle) {
      parent.style.width = "100%";
    } else {
      parent.style.width = "15%";
    }

  });
}());
```

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 15%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  transition: width 400ms ease-in-out;
}

.parent-2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 15%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.icons {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
  font-size: 60px;
}

.icons:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="parent"></div>
<div class="parent-2">
  <div class="icons">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Of course! I wasn't "thinking outside of the div" so to speak. :) Great suggestion and it answers my question.